# Pass data to another thread, java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating a small application learning about Java threading. I want to have a thread running that will analyze a small piece of data (a poker hand), and output a display message when the hand is detected to be a winning hand.

I already have the part completed that generates hands until the deck is empty, I just need to figure out how to pass that data over into the other thread which analyzes and triggers the display message (just a simple System.out).

I'd like to do this to a currently running thread, instead of spawning a new thread for every hand that is dealt and passing the cards in the constructor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck myDeck = new PokerDeck();
        DeckHandlerInterface deckHandler = new DeckHandler();

        (new Thread(new ThreadWin())).start();

        for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            while(myDeck.getDeck().size() >= deckHandler.getHandSize()) {
                deckHandler.dealHand(myDeck.getDeck());
            }
                    deckHandler.resetDeck();
        }

    }
```

My deckHandler returns a collection object which is what I want to pass to the other thread. That's the part I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Sure. Show us what you have so far, and any failed attempts.

Comment: Added the code snippet, and a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a couple of [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)s. Have the thread that generates hands stick the hands in one queue. The thread checking hands polls that queue and checks any hands it finds. Then it writes the results to a 2nd queue which the hand-generating thread can poll and display.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this.

A simple approach might be to create a `Queue` that you pass in a reference to via the `ThreadWin` constructor.
Then you just add the objects you wish to pass to the queue from the main thread, and listen for new objects on the queue in your `ThreadWin` thread. In particular it seems like a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) might be a good fit here.

Comment: Is there also a way to do this with Executor? Or am I misunderstanding the concept of it?

Comment: @Organiccat: Whether you use `Executor` or not doesn't really change your situation. That only affects how the threads are started and managed. If you wish to pass data to a running thread you need some kind of message channel, for example a `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want your "ThreadWin" to observe (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) the DeckHandler

Basically, the ThreadWin thread will "register" with the DeckHandler so it gets notified when the DeckHandler gets a new batch of PokerHands.

When the ThreadWin thread is notified it will "stop resting" and determine which hand was best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to create simple consumer-producer scenario, there is even a simple example in the documentation.

You should also read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to have a better understanding of concurrency.

Propably the best method is to use java.util.concurrent package threadpool to execute tasks. Threadpool are nice, easy to implement, but you will not learn much apart from using the threadpools.